# docker: Error response from daemon: invalid mode: /usr/src/app

Tags: linux, docker, owasp

I'm running the owasp zap docker image in AWS codebuild and created a python container to run the zap instance, but i'm receiving the below error:

Docker Command: Here, zappy is name of the ZAP container

- docker run --privileged --rm --name dast -v zappy:/home/zap:/usr/src/app -w /usr/src/app python3:zapv2 python dast.py

Error:  docker: Error response from daemon: invalid mode: /usr/src/app

Comment: Run `ls -la /usr/src/app` what is the output?

Comment: Where is /home/zap, what are you trying to mount with the volume?

Comment: Output: No such file or directory, but when i created the python container it is created in /usr/src/app

Comment: @BMitch- /home/zap is the zap container which contains all the custom scripts that i want to run in the python conatiner, so i 'm mounting so that scripts get executed in this call docker run --privileged --rm --name dast -v zappy:/home/zap:/usr/src/app -w /usr/src/app python3:zapv2 python dast.py

Comment: resolved the issue: docker run -i -d --rm --name dastpoc -v /home/zap:/usr/src/app -w /usr/src/app python3:zapv2 python dastpoc.py

Answer (score 0):

You can't mount volumes from a directory inside of another container like that. In the volume short syntax, three colons in a string get split as volume source (name or path, in your case the named volume is zappy), the container path (this is the container you are creating, so/home/zap would be created in the container you are running), and finally mount options for the volume like read only flags or SE Linux settings (/usr/src/app is not a valid option for the mount). The two options to mount volumes between containers I know of are:

**Option A**: use `--volumes-from zappy` to mount all volumes in the zappy container into your new container. You have no control of the volume path in the target container, it will mount with the same path of the volume in the source container. This also isn't supported in newer versions of docker compose files.

**Option B**: use a common volume, typically a named volume, between the two containers.

Note that a named volume would be initialized by the first container to be created, so note the startup order.

The resulting command would look like:

```
docker run --privileged --rm --name dast \
  -v zappy-home:/usr/src/app \
  -w /usr/src/app \
  python3:zapv2 python dast.py
```

And the zappy container would have a `-v zappy-home:/home/zap` as part of it's creation.

Comment: Thanks @BMitch- It Worked by adding -i -d in the below command / docker run -i -d --rm --name dastpoc -v /home/zap:/usr/src/app -w /usr/src/app python3:zapv2 python dastpoc.py

Comment: @VikrantReddy good to hear. Be sure to check the answer if your problem is solved so that it doesn't show as unanswered to others.